# Check "Use Default Value" for super attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, superattribute

In the BO, when I go on a `configurable product > associated products`, I have this following block :
[image]

I want to check the checkbox "use default" for my configurable products.

When I load the product, I can't access to this super attribute :

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id)->setStoreId($store_id);
```

I can access this variable with this code :

```
$productAttributeOptions = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($product);
```

But now, I can't make any modification (I though make something like that : `$product->setData($attr, false)->save();`)

Someone have any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer to my issue. I post the link if someone is interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28982132/set-super-product-attributes-attribute-name-to-use-default